# increment text box name by 1 in a loop

Tags: vb.net

ok so I've done numerous searches and come up with the following code to increment up the text box name, but it just does not work. The text box is within a tab control does this matter? I've tried to reference it within the tab control but no joy.

```
 Public Cpv_Coeffs As New List(Of Decimal)

        Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 6
        'Cpv_Coeffs.Add(txt_Cp_Coef_A1.Text) 'this line works fine
        Cpv_Coeffs.Add(Me.Controls("txt_Cp_Coef_A" & 1).Text)
    Next i
```

i just get a null reference exception
where am I going wrong?

Comment: If the TextBox is in a TabControl, you need to change the `Me.Controls` to `tabPage.Controls` where tabPage is the name of the tab that has the controls

Comment: Also, you need to be using `& i` rather than `& 1`, otherwise you'll just get the same control every time. It might also help if you were to add `Decimal` values to your `List(Of Decimal)` rather than `Strings`. If you had `Option Strict On`, which you pretty much always should, then that code would not compile.

Comment: thanks JayV. that has fixed it . Jmc, sorry typo with my post it should have read & i+1

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work, no matter which container the control is in, then use the [Controls.Find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.7.2) fucntion.  It can recursively search for the control no matter how deeply nested it is:

```
Public Cpv_Coeffs As New List(Of Decimal)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ctlName As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To 6
        ctlName = "txt_Cp_Coef_A" & i
        Dim ctl As Control = Me.Controls.Find(ctlName, True).FirstOrDefault
        If Not IsNothing(ctl) AndAlso TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
            Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(ctl, TextBox)
            Dim dcml As Decimal
            If Decimal.TryParse(tb.Text, dcml) Then
                Cpv_Coeffs.Add(dcml)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Value: " & tb.Text, "Invalid Decimal")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Name: " & ctlName & vbCrLf & "Could Not Find Control, or it was not a TextBox.", "Error")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The above example is verbose, but it shows you exactly where all the failure points could occur.

Comment: thanks for this, presumably from a performance point of view I'm better specifying the control when I do know it rather than searching for it ?

Comment: Absolutely.  If you can access it directly, it will be faster; searching will be slower.